# Disable or hide webBrowser scrolling bars

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I need to hide the scrolling bars from my web Browser.

I've tried the 'ScrollBarsEnabled' property, but only the horizontal bar disappeared.

My question:

How can I remove both scroll bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following style in your web page's head section.

```
<style>
html{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```